# Can I make a private network using a wifi extender?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-extender

I live in an apartment building where all the tenants have access to a shared WiFi network.
I bought a WiFi extender ([A WavLink WL-WN575A3](https://www.newegg.com/wavlink-wl-wn575a3-1/p/1A7-0019-00011)) with the goal of improving the signal strength in my apartment, and also so that I could create a private network to, among other things, make my printer accessible over WiFi without making it available to all my neighbors.

I've set up the extender with a different SSID and password from the apartment WiFi and connected my computer to the new network, but when I open Windows Explorer (this is Windows 10 Home) and look at the Network devices, it's still showing me other people's computers, which are presumably connected to the Apartment Wifi. Is there a good way to make it so that the devices that are connected to my extender can only see and be seen by other devices on the extender?

Comment: No - the wifi extender is just repeating a pre-existing signal, it doesn't create a separate local network. Does it boost the signal? Yes, but a repeater only does that.

Comment: The hardware can do it, no doubt. However, consumer-grade network equipment only has limited software capabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get the desired behavior, but not with the firmware that the extender shipped with. Fortunately, the fine people at the OpenWRT project have made [a version for this device](https://openwrt.org/toh/wavlink/wl-wn575a3) with simple installation instructions.

If I remember right, it didn't work at first after I followed the instructions, but after I held down the reset button I was able to connect without issue. I'm not 100% sure that was the sequence of events, so I'm not going to recommend adding it to the instructions, but it's something to try if it's not working right.

Once I got OpenWRT working, I set up one of the device's two radios as a WAN DHCP client to connect to the apartment Wifi (I created a new interface for this), and the other as a LAN DHCP server. If I wanted 5GHz capability, I suspect I could put both functions on one radio, but this seems to be working, and that's good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

As @pigeonburger pointed out, the wifi extender just extends the reach of the signal. However, it's important to consider if the device supports other operation modes.

> Is there a good way to make it so that the devices that are connected to my extender can only see and be seen by other devices on the extender?

Yes, what you want in that case is a router with NAT and DHCP functionality. Most routers one can buy for private use have this enabled by default.
The specific device you linked claims to be a `Repeater / Access Point / Router`. As you can see on the fourth page of the link you posted there are dedicated buttons to switch the mode to `router`.

<strike>If the device doesn't actually turn out to support this you can get tge desired network segregation by buying a wifi router and connecting the uplink to the `WAN` port.</strike>

Comment: The router mode doesn't let you put in information for the WAN WiFi, so I guess it only works as a Wired-to-Wireless router. Seems less than useful on a device billed as a WiFi extender, but at least there's a workaround.